# How do I determine the number of seeks performed on Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance-monitoring, benchmark

I have two programs that write to my servers disk.

One I wrote, it does linear writes, it's writing data quickly. Another I'm benchmarking, it's writing data at a 3rd of the speed. It doesn't do much else, and I believe the problem is caused by the second program seeking more (i.e. it does more random file access).

Is there a tool on Linux I can use to determine the number of seeks being performed on a particular disk? Or by a particular process?

Comment: what os you're running

Comment: @SohamChakraborty, it is right there in the title.  Linux.

Comment: I needed to know what distro. I can read that it is linux, but you know there are multiple flavors of linux

Answer (score 0):

This tool might help you http://sourceforge.net/projects/hdparm/ - i have used this in the past with some success. The other tools which can give you a benchmark is iometer. Iostat is another tool but that might not show you processes and this tool might also help http://www.atoptool.nl/. Hope that helps!

Comment: `man hdparm` shows no option to query the number of seek operations performed by the hard drive so far

Answer (score 0):

For determining the number of *seek* calls per process you can use `strace` and search for every interesting system call (*fseek(o)*, *lseek(64)*, *llseek* etc.). Better just `grep` for *seek* to see which functions are called by that particular process.

Examples:

```
lseek(3, -1467, SEEK_CUR)               = 842
```

The file opened via file descriptor *3* is set to *-1467* bytes from the *current* position, resulting in a new position of *842* bytes.

```
lseek(12, 40267, SEEK_SET)              = 40267
```

The file opened via file descriptor *12* is set to the *total* position of *40267* bytes resulting in a new position of *40267* bytes (which equals *success* as both numbers are the same).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it might be revealing to look at the load impact and behaviour of the storage system:

```
iostat -x 1
```

There are several values of interest there:

- `avgrq-sz` describes the size (in sectors) of requests sent to the disk
- `avgqu-sz` shows the length of this queue (think no. of transactions)
- `await` displays the time spent waiting for device access (until the device starts processing the request)
- `svctm` shows the time the device spent to satisfy the requests

In your case, request size should go up for your description of linear writes, while queue length and device utilization should stay medium to low.
In your second case of more random access patterns the request size should stay lower but the queue size, access wait and utilization should go up.

Depending on the access patterns it might make sense to tune `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs` or the `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio`, but this depends on the amount and pattern of data moved (just to give you a pointer of where the tune-ables for the page cache/write cache are).

Comment: While `iostat` can give you rough guesses, it does not show the real number of disk seeks the hardware is doing. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083324/linux-monitor-number-of-disk-seeks-per-second